# Как правильно писать вне-игровой, внеигровой или вне игровой

Tags: правописание

Как правильно писать вне-игровой, внеигровой или вне игровой

Comment: Первое неверно. Второе и третье возможно и зависит от контекста.

Answer (score 6):

Проверка - можно ли убрать "игровой".

Если нет - то слитно: "У него ещё были внеигровые успехи."
Если да - раздельно: "Вне игровой ситуации у нас совершенно другие ощущения." Потому что слово "игровой" можно перенести: "Вне ситуации (которая игровая)".